# java.nio.channels.DatagramChannel basic UDP RX client connect

Tags: java, udp, nio

Trying to do a basic UDP client receiver with java.nio.channels.DatagramChannel. I have the following put together:

```
DatagramChannel dc = DatagramChannel.open();
dc.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_RCVBUF, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
dc.configureBlocking(true);
int listeningPort = 4445;
dc.connect(new InetSocketAddress(listeningPort));
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(2048);
dc.read(byteBuffer);
```

I am getting a bind exception on my call to connect:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: connect
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
```

I have tried switching the port around with no luck... any thoughts?

I have been following:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/datagram-channel.html

If I do the:

```
dc.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(listeningPort));
```

instead of connect, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.channels.NotYetConnectedException
at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done something similar before, that's the bit of my code:

```
    DatagramChannel datagramChannel = DatagramChannel.open();
    DatagramSocket datagramSocket = datagramChannel.socket();
    datagramSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
    datagramSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(HOST, PORT));
    datagramSocket.connect(address);
    datagramChannel.configureBlocking(false);

    datagramChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
```

My `HOST = "localhost"`
and `PORT = 19000`

Comment: that's a Channel selector `import java.nio.channels.Selector;` and then `selector = Selector.open();`

Comment: Cool, this helps. Looks like the problem is with my InetSocketAddress. Works if I specify "localhost". I need it to bind to all interfaces though?

Comment: [Here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/selectors.html) some more about the selectors

Comment: yea, was looking at that. I am thinking I don't need it since I only have one channel

Comment: yeah, then is no sense to use it, unless u want to add channels later on

Comment: Right on, will give you the check and the vote as soon as I confirm I can send from a remote host. Thanks!